# Computer networking: During what transmission round is the 70th segment sent?

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols

While practicing some exercises I came across the following exercises that I just can't wrap my head around. Looking at the solution, I don't get how they reach to the conclusion that packet 32 to 63 are sent in the 6th transmission round. How was 63 computed?

[image]

**During what transmission round is the 70th segment sent?**

**Solution:**

```
During the 1st transmission round, packet 1 is sent; 
packet 2-3 are sent in the 2nd transmission round; 
packets 4-7 are sent in the 3rd transmission round; 
packets 8-15 are sent in the 4th transmission round;
packets 16 to 31 are sent in the 5th transmission round; 
packets 32 to 63 are sent in the 6th transmission round; 
packets 64 to 96 are sent in the 7th transmission round. 
Thus packet 70 is sent in the 7th transmission round.
```

Comment: What exercises? Could you please provide a link?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant but exercises are from https://mosi.uni-saarland.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Homework6-solutionc.pdf

Answer (score 3):

With the Exercise link provided, we can see that the TCP transmission moves from Slow Start to Congestion Avoidance at Transmission Round 6 in Exercise 1, (we can see we the graph change gradient, next paragraph as to why).

As per `RFC 2001 Article .1 & .2` ([link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2001)), we can see that when we move into TCP Congestion Avoidance the Congestion Window Size (cwnd), the segment size shall increase by only 1 per Transmission Round.

Again looking at the exercise (and your notes above), we see the following segment sizes being transmitted (**it's important to notice the packets are inclusive**, so transmission round 6 contains 32 packets, round 7 contains 33 packets):

```
During the 1st transmission round, packet 1 is sent;      | Current Window Size of (1)
packet 2-3 are sent in the 2nd transmission round;        | Increase window by 1 segment (2)
packets 4-7 are sent in the 3rd transmission round;       | Increase window by 2 segments (4)
packets 8-15 are sent in the 4th transmission round;      | Increase window by 4 segments (8)
packets 16 to 31 are sent in the 5th transmission round;  | Increase window by 8 segments (16)
packets 32 to 63 are sent in the 6th transmission round;  | Increase window by 16 segments (32)
*** Here we switch to Congestion Avoidance
packets 64 to 96 are sent in the 7th transmission round.  | Increase windows by 1 segment (33)
```

As the packets are inclusive, the exercise is correct by stating that packet 32, all the way up to and including packet 63 (so let's imagine the end of packet 63 being essentially the beginning of packet 64) make up transmission round 6.